# Audio Features Extraction using Python

Tags: python, audio, feature-extraction

How to calculate Audio Features Like Tempo , Energy ,Dancability ... using python?
I want method that extract features from Audio File directly !

Comment: Have you tried using first your favourite search engine? Go through tutorials, see how it goes. If you have a **programming** question, post it here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Additional audio feature extraction tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55665911/additional-audio-feature-extraction-tips)

Answer (score 1):

Try the Librosa package.

```
pip install librosa
```

e.g., for tempo:

```
import librosa

y, sr = librosa.load('path/to/audiofile.wav')
onset_env = librosa.onset.onset_strength(y, sr=sr)
tempo = librosa.beat.tempo(onset_envelope=onset_env, sr=sr)
```

For a range of features which can be extracted with librosa see [here](https://librosa.org/doc/main/feature.html):